# Publishing multiple applications within a project

Tags: android, google-play, multiple-apk

I want to develop an android application that screen design and source code are same but contents of screen (background color, images, font, text etc.) are different for each client. How can I configure the project?

This android project should have contents of multiple customers. But when publishing the application in GooglePlay, I need to publish all customer apps at one time. So each customer their own application be able to see their logo and name on the market and be able to download. How can I do this?

Comment: Automate everything using git and gradle.